# XMP tag replaces my style with another

Tags: html, css

I found the XMP tag, as very useful for copying everything verbatim until the ending xmp tag.

```
<XMP> '<b>aaa</b>' </XMP>
```

The generated css:

```
pre, xmp, plaintext, listing {
display: block;
font-family: monospace;
white-space: pre;
margin: 1em 0px;
}
```

But it replaces my css (e.g- font) text to another font:
[xmp example](http://dadinck.x10.mx/xmp.html).

How can I use this tag, but keep my fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xmp` element causes by default the font to be set to a system-dependent monospace font. It may also cause the font size to be reduced somewhat. To prevent these, set

```
xmp { font-family: inherit; font-size: 100% }
```

A little safer way (due to lack of support to `inherit` in some old browsers) is to set the font face in the same context where you set it on the page as a whole or on the enclosing element. Example:

```
body, xmp { font-family: Cambria, Georgia; } 
xmp { font-size: 100% }
```